# Use js object params with variable property

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I have following array.

```
[searchEngineOrder] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword
            [1] => Google
            [2] => Yahoo
            [3] => Bing/MSN
        )

      [Datagrid] => Array
        (
            [Brand] => Array
                (                    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [keyword] => About Jetwing Hotels Sri Lanka
                            [Google] => 1
                            [Yahoo] => 1
                            [Bing/MSN] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [keyword] => Dining at Jetwing Kurulubedda
                            [Google] => 1
                            [Yahoo] => 1
                            [Bing/MSN] => 1
                        )
           )       )
```

This is php array. (i use json encoding)

Now i want to create table. I used following code.

var headers = data.searchEngineOrder;

```
        var trs = '<tr><td>Brand</td></tr>';

        var brands = data.Datagrid.Brand;

        for (x in brands) {
            trs += '<tr>';
            for (y in headers) {                    
               // trs += '<td>'+ brands[x].keyword +'</td>';  This is work               
               trs += '<td>'+ brands[x].headers[y] +'</td>';  //This is not work    
            }
            trs += '</tr>';
        }

        $('#keyword-table tbody').html(trs);
```

As above code  `brands[x].keyword` or  brands[x].Google is work. But when i used keyword or Google as variable it is not work.

Please help me. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is bracketed notation with a string:

```
brands[x]["keyword"]
```

In JavaScript, you can access object properties (which is what these are) in two ways:

1. Using dot notation and a literal property name, e.g. `foo.property`.
2. Using bracketed notation and a string property name, e.g. `foo["property"]`.

   In this second case, the string doesn't have to be a literal string, it can be the result of any expression — including a variable reference. So:

   ```
   var k = "keyword";
   var value = brands[x][k];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
brands[x][headers[y]];
```

i.e. you take the `brand` with key `x`, and then look up the `header` with key `y` and then use *that* name as the variable name of a property of the `brand`.